# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql

I was trying to connect to my database through PHP but I keep getting the error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

I do not know what the problem is?

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
  //Connect to the server
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

  //Connect to the database
  mysql_select_db("firstdatab");

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FavNumber = '44' ");
  //Get Results

  $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  $first_name = $rows['Name'];
  echo "$first_name";
?>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I don't know why this won't migrate to StackOverflow.

Comment: @JohnConde I am blocked on Stack Overflow. I dont know why and I cannot fix it.

Comment: Asking coding questions on Webmasters is not the appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your code looks fine so your problem lies elsewhere. You need to use [`mysql_error()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to tell you what you problem is.

```
<?php


//Connect to the server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

//Connect to the database
mysql_select_db("firstdatab");


$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FavNumber = '44' ");

if ($results)
{
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
    $first_name = $rows['Name'];
    echo "$first_name";
}
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: I just tried it and it came back with: Table 'firstdatab.users' doesn't exist

Comment: There's your problem right there.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Sorry Im kind of new to php and mysql

Comment: Execute these: 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `firstdatab`;' then 'CREATE TABLE `firstdatab`.`users` (`Name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL) ENGINE = MyISAM;' and insert your data.